# Ubuntu/Gnome 17.10: maximze window top/bottom shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, window-management

The new Gnome settings do not have keyboard shortcut for maximizing the window top/bottom.  Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Gnome extension does this and it works pretty well.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/

Comment: Wayland is not supported